# Массовое подключение шрифтов для сайта

Tags: css, шрифты

Всем доброго времени суток!

Необходимо подобрать шрифт для главной сайта.
Скачал архивчик, который содержит штук 30 стилей. Если их все подключать по отдельности через `@font-face`, то я поседею, когда закончу их подключать.

Может, можно как-то подключить сразу все? Как библиотеку `( *src.bla.** )`.

Comment: 30 шрифтов это дело 20 минут максимум, а вот искать и подключать плагин (если такой вообще есть) для парсинга папок шрифтов и генерации css у вас на сайте, вот тут точно поседеете, пока сделаете.

Как альтернативный вариант, попробуйте поискать ваши шрифты в шрифтах гугла, либо на fonts.com каком-нибудь, где можно с помощью скрипта для сайта подключить все доступные у них шрифты.

Comment: Тоже верно. Написал скрипт,который парсит папку, и формирует готовый css для подключения.

Answer (score 3):

Список сайтов для конвертации шрифтов

1) https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator

2) https://onlinefontconverter.com

3) https://fontie.pixelsvsbytes.com/webfont-generator

Google Fonts - https://www.google.com/fonts

Comment: Только вот на fontsquirrel.com есть одна проблема, палёные шрифты не хотят кушать, а так да, сервис очень хороший, конвертирует и даёт готовый css.

Answer (score 0):

Если проблему описывать как "*подобрать какой-то шрифт для главной*", а не "*как подключить сразу кучу заранее скачанных шрифтов*", то могу порекомендовать расширение для [Google Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webfonting-it/lpfegdkicphlldcdfeomhdochopplghk?hl=ru) (есть и версия для [Opera](https://addons.opera.com/ru/extensions/details/webfonting-it/?display=ru))